# Hint needed in volume integral computation: Finding the volume in the first octant inside of $y^2+z^2=16$ but outside $y^2=3x$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I am looking for a hint about how to set up the bounds incorporating the information "outside of $y^2=3x$. I know that this should look like a cylinder along the $x$ axis, the parabola $y^2=3x$ slicing off just a small triangle type slice of it in the first octant. The way I set this up was as follows:

$$\int_0^3\int_{y^2/3}^3 \sqrt{16-y^2}dxdy$$

Which gives me 3 times the answer. I am supposed to use two integrals, but would be fine using more if that is easier.

Comment: Is it $y^2+z^2=16$ (title) or $y^2+z^2=9$ (integral)?

Comment: In $\mathbb{R^3}$, $y^2=3x$ is not the equation of a parabola but of a parabolic cylinder. I have not had time enough to think about the issue, but it looks like you need a triple integral...

Comment: @aretino 16 sorry will edit.

Comment: You should then check the integration limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_0^4\int_{0}^{y^2/3} \sqrt{16-y^2}dxdy.$$